# Navbar with Title in center and buttons to right

Tags: html, css, navbar, display

So I'm attempting to create a navbar with a title in the center and a button that appears to the right. As you can see, when I attempt to do it, the button appears on the next line and out of the div:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ck18vjpn/1/)

```css
.title-bar {
  background-color: #48A6B8;
  font-style: italic;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  color: #fff;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 180%;
}

.buts {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="title-bar">
  <div class="title">Title</div>
  <div class="button">
    <button class="buts">Whats Up</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

`display:inline-block` seems to remove the centering of the text so I can't use that...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `flexbox`

`flex: 1 0 auto;` will make `title` flexible, it will acquire all available free space in [flex-container](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes#Flexible_Boxes_Vocabulary).

```css
.title-bar {
  background-color: #48A6B8;
  font-style: italic;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 180%;
  flex:1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="title-bar">
  <div class="title">Title</div>
  <div class="button">
    <button class="buts">Whats Up</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Edit: after @burak's comment that it's not in exactly center.

As you can see in the below image, some of the space is acquired by the <kbd>Whats Up</kbd> button, that's why title is not in the exact center but Text is in the exact center of it's parent.

[image]

We can make it in exact center as well, but for that we'll need to shift <kbd>Whats Up</kbd> button on another layer, by using `position:absolute`

```css
.title-bar {
  background-color: #48A6B8;
  font-style: italic;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  position:relative;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 180%;
  flex:1 0 auto;
  
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.5)
}

.button{
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="title-bar">
  <div class="title">Title</div>
  <div class="button">
    <button class="buts">Whats Up</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Title is NOT exactly at center.

Comment: @Burak, I have mentioned that *it will acquire all available free space...* because it has button as well, that's why it's not in exact center, it's in center after reducing the space of button.

Answer (score 3):

I used a flexbox for the title bar and let the required margin at the left be calculated automatically.

```css
.title-bar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.title, .button {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="title-bar">
  <div class="title">Title</div>
  <div class="button">
    <button class="buts">Whats Up</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use display:inline; so that title and button both will appear on same line.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.title-bar {
  background-color: #48A6B8;
  font-style: italic;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  position:relative;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 180%;
  flex:1 0 auto;
  
}

.buttonRight{
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="title-bar">
  <div class="title">Title</div>
  <div class="buttonRight">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Whats Up</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Nothing more changes done here, only changes made in CSS, just compare CSS only, it fixes the position of your right button.