# How to I create a centered title on my website with subtitles right justified using navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I want to create a title similar to this

[image: Title centered properly]

```css
.title-bar {
  background-color: #48A6B8;
  font-style: italic;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  position:relative;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 180%;
  flex:1 0 auto;
  
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.5)
}

.button{
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="title-bar">
  <div class="title">Title</div>
  <div class="button">
    <button class="buts">Whats Up</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Found from here:
[Navbar with Title in center and buttons to right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45628473/navbar-with-title-in-center-and-buttons-to-right)

and I am using the navbar bootstrap documentation instead.
Found here:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

How do I create a centered title with menu buttons on the right side as well without having it look like this.

[image: Title not centered properly]

I am using the navbar bootstrap documentation because I want the navbar to work for mobile as well. Is it possible to accomplish this using the navbar from bootstrap 4.0?

My current code can be found below:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Arvo:wght@700&display=swap");
body {
    background-color: #e9d4d0;
    padding-top: 68px;
}

.navbar {
    font-family: "Arvo", serif !important;
    background-color: #c8a36d;
}

.nav-item {
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
}

#title {
    /* width: 100vw;*/
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

            <div class="mx-auto">
                <h2 class="navi">Title</h2>
            </div>

            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">


                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Our Product</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Our Vision</a>
                </li>
            </ul>



        </div>
    </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

and the output of it is:
[image: My broken navbar]

I am wondering how I can make the Title centered and the About Us/Our Product/Our Vision can still work as buttons

Comment: Seems to work in your snippet. Is there something else in your other code in your environment? EDIT: Did you just copy the code from the answer from the other question? If so, you need to post what you actually have. Right now, your question contains working code and will be confusing to people trying to help you.

Comment: @disinfor I have updated the question to make more sense now. I forgot to include my code and example. I want to adjust my example with the brown background to make the example with the blue background and centered title.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want?

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" />
  <style>
    @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Arvo:wght@700&display=swap");
    body {
      background-color: #e9d4d0;
    }
    
    .navbar {
      font-family: "Arvo", serif !important;
      background-color: #c8a36d;
    }
    
    .nav-item {
      padding-left: 8px;
      padding-right: 8px;
    }
    
    #title {
      /* width: 100vw;*/
      height: 100vh;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <h2 class="navi m-0 col-8 text-center">Title</h2>
      <div class="col-4 text-end">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Our Product</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Our Vision</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```